# LiveCycle Designer ES 4 Master Page Assistance

Tags: designer, livecycle

I am a new user to LiveCycle (LiveCycle ES4 to be exact) and am having an issue with my second Master Page. I only want the second Mast Page to appear if the content from Page 1 overflows onto Page 2. I have tried changing the "Presence" on the second MasterPage to Hidden but the program won't allow me to choose any option other than Visible.

I have tried Google and Adobe and both have basic information regarding Master Pages but nothing specific enough to help me in this situation. Actually, I haven't been able to find a source with any real helpful information regarding LiveCycle.

Comment: Set your first page subform (Page1 i.e. below the master page set) to:
Overflow -> Top of <second master page>

Answer (score 1):

On the main page that represents your flowed page, in the Object properties tab, if you select the Pagination tab, you can set overflow properties of this page to use your second master page (ensure it is named so you can reference it).  If your first page never overflows, then you should never see the other master page.